# Unsure how to solve this proof

Tags: limits, proof-writing

I came across this in my textbook and was wondering how it could be proved. My only thought is that contradiction should be used. Thank you for any help!

> *Suppose $L = \lim_{k \to \infty} X_k$. Then If $(x_k)^\infty_{k=1}$ is nondecreasing then $x_k \le L$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.*

Answer (score 0):

For an increasing sequence $\{x_k\}_k$,
$$
\lim_k x_k = \sup_k x_k.
$$
You just use the definition of supremum and the uniqueness of the limit. Therefore $L \geq x_k$ for every $k$.

*Hint*: let $S=\sup_k x_k$. Then, given $\epsilon>0$, there is $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $S-\epsilon < x_{k_0} \leq S$. By monotonicity, for every $k \geq k_0$ there results $S-\epsilon< x_{k_0} \leq x_k$, and you conclude that $S=\lim_k x_k$.